# Border drag end for dismissible widget

Tags: android, flutter, widget, padding, dismissible

When I wrap listtile in card with dismissible widget into another card or container as in the screenshot in the link, when I drag the dismissible card, it goes out of the parent card that wraps it. 
I don't want it to go outside the white card area in the screenshot in the link.

[image: dismissible screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [`clipBehavour`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card/clipBehavior.html) of your `Card` to any of the `Clip.hardEdge`, `Clip.antiAlias`, `Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer`. This clips the content of your card when drawing.

You should read up on the clipping behaviour, artifacts and trade-offs in the [`Clip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Clip-class.html) documentation as different behaviors result in different results in terms of aliasing and performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very effective property. It worked very well.